# DocuSign module Connect does not publish to the provided URL

Tags: docusignapi

I have enabled the DocuSign Connect module and enabled the logging. Unfortunately there will be no calls to the provided URL and no logging at all. I have enabled all events but still no action. I use the API to send a sign request and then sign the document via the email link sent out from DocuSign. I followed the documentation but without success. Did I missed anything to administrate to use Connect?

Comment: Have you specified the correct "Select users to integrate"? You need to generate envelopes from users that have been selected in this section - or take a blanket 'all users integrated' checkbox approach.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your configuration via the UI (you can exclude your URL)

Answer (score 1):

It's working now. The only thing I have changed is that I've set up the configuration again with the new UI instead of using the classic view. So I unfortunately can't figure out which step exactly didn't work with the old UI. However it is working now. Thanks!